# Point of sale performance testing

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, point-of-sale

I am working on a approach to performance test Point of sale application. 
Has anyone performance tested POS systems? If so how would the environment setup look like for performance testing? Do we need to setup multiple POS systems to simulate the required TPS or can we trigger multiple transactions from one POS system?

Basically, i am not trying to test the POS application by itself, I am trying to measure the time taken to send the request and get the response back to POS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You need to specifically look at your requirements for your point of sale system and whether the focus is on the performance of the local device or the remote systems that the device connects to, either in-store or potentially across the country/internet.   You also need to be very well aware of what is in your control versus what is not (such as credit card authorization times) when you start reporting on the performance of your system.

On the long question on whether you actually need to have the devices when you run a test?  If the focus is the back end systems that all of the POS devices connect to, then no.  You only need to exercise the interfaces of the back end systems the same way as the front end devices.   Most modern systems are using a variant of standard protocols for communication so there is often a method to proxy the call to record.   If not then these items can often be reconstructed from protocol analyzer (Wireshark/sniffer/...) traces or database logs containing the queries and sequence from the front end client.

if all of the requirements point to front end performance then you need really only a couple of variants on the device you are testing and the vast majority of your efforts, save for perhaps a network impairment device to slow down the network representing a congested environment, will be manual.  Get your stopwatches ready.

Comment: Thanks James. Yes, my focus is to only test the back-end systems and not the actual POS software. The POS application that i am testing uses socket communication to talk to the back-end systems. It also uses SSL. I am able to capture the request that is sent via the socket , but for some reason, i am not able to send the string request (via loadrunner) to the back-end interface. Not sure if its due to connection issue or SSL error.

Comment: SSL generally denotes an HTTP stream.  Take a protocol analyzer (Wireshark, Sniffer, etc...) and look at the protocol stream between your device and the back end.  You may find something that you can capture via proxy on the SSL front.

Comment: I know it's late. You can use Load Multiplier tool to test back end server. In addition to HTTP/HTTPS transactions, you can do any text / binary message transactions using Load Multiplier tool.

Answer (score 0):

By your question I am understanding that you want to have performance testing on the switch or the gateway, where you pos transaction is hitting.

Checking the time for your terminal to generate the payment packet, encrypting the packet and hitting the switch / gateway. Though this will depend on the internet speed and other network dependencies, so you can just collect the data and I don't think this will not help you lot.

By generating multiple payment request from different terminals, and making transaction, you are not actually testing the performance testing of terminal, but the performance testing of the switch or the gateway. Easy way to do this, is to keep sending the payment request from Simulated POS software.

By performance testing of POS terminal, I would rather check on below point:

1) Testing the stability and performance of the software modules in POS
2) What is the success rate of detecting the contactless card, chip card and MSR swipe
3) Test the integration of the POS terminal software
4) Check for the time require to reboot the terminal
5) Check for any un-wanted code / app residing in the POS software